# Java Remainder of Integer Divison?

Tags: java, math, divide

I was searching around about this topic but I still don't get it, if someone can elaborate I would be very thankful.

My task is to divide two variables as integer division with remainder..
The problem is, that I have no clue what a remainder is, for now I did something like that, this is what I found by searching through the internet:

```
int a;
int b;
int remainder = Math.Pow(a,2) % b;

System.out.println("a^2 / b = " + Math.Pow(a,2) / b);
System.out.println("remainder = " + remainder);
```

if I for example set (a = 43) and (b = 67)

Then I will get this reslut:

```
a^2 / b = 27
remainder = 40
```

Now since I have no idea what the remainder is (this is just a suggestion form the internet) I have no idea if this is the correct answer..?

Thanks for any help,

Kind Regards

Comment: In an integer division the remainder is what doesn't fit into the divisor, i.e. if you calculate 11/4 the integer result will be 2 (4 fits 2 times into 11) and a remainder of 3 (since 11 - 2*4 = 3). Or put another way: if you have 11 apples and want to give them equally to 4 people you can only give each person 2 apples and then have 3 left (remaining).

Comment: "since I have no idea what the remainder is" - so you not understand what remainders are? 43*43 is 1849, and 1849 divided by 67 is 27, with a remainder of 40 - as 27 * 67 = 1809. It's not clear what your question is here. It's a little like saying "here's code to do addition... it says that 4 + 5 is 9, but I'm not sure whether that's right or not".

Comment: Okay thanks.. english is not my native tongue so maybe that's why I didn't understand.. and also because I suck at maths.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are looking for the mathematical modulo operation you could use

```
int x = -22;
int y = 24;
System.out.println(Math.floorMod(x, y));
```

If you are not interested in the mathematical modulo (just the remainder) then you could use

```
int x = -22;
int y = 24;
System.out.println(x%y);
```

Comment: If you need the modulo calculation (for a positive `y`) you can also perform the trick `((x % y) + y) % y`, but beware that this may cause an integer overflow (for very large values of `y`). It does however skip the function call. This is an optimization however, and should be applied only where required.

Answer (score 8):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dividend = 139, divisor = 7;

        int quotient = dividend / divisor;
        int remainder = dividend % divisor;

        System.out.println("The Quotient is = " + quotient);
        System.out.println("The Remainder is = " + remainder);
    }
```

**Output:**

> The Quotient is = 19
>
> The Remainder is = 6

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `%` operator will return the remainder of the Integer division.

To know more about the remainder of the Integer division check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#Integer_division):

> If a and d are integers, with d non-zero, it can be proven that there exist unique integers q and r, such that a = qd + r and 0 ≤ r < |d|. The number q is called the quotient, while r is called the remainder.

Comment: More or less, I still need to know how to do it in the code.. but as I understand now using the %-operator is the correct way to do it..

Comment: Yes it is. Just eddited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

`int remainder = a % b;` will sort you. The remainder operator returns the remainder of the division.

---

Note that the remainder operator is also called the modulo operator. However, this is incorrect for Java as Java will return a negative value if the left operand `a` is negative.

Comment: It's not a modulo operator. It's a remainder operator. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @DisasterCoder depends on your specifications of implementation. Do you want it to be a simple remainder(it can have negative values), or the mathematical correct modulo operation.

Comment: For this task I believe it's only the simple remainder that is asked, however to know both ways would be best right? So what's the mathematical correct modulo operation?

Answer (score 0):

`%` operator will return the remainder of the Integer division.

> What modules actually does under the hood ?

Modules tend to remove `cycles` from the number, until it reaches a positive number that is smaller than the number of the cycle which we call modulo `OR` a negative number which we call a `reminder`.

However, Using `%` operator is time expensive.

> To avoid using  `%` while getting the same result, we can use the following:

- `While(a >= n) a -= n;` (when `a` is a positive number)
- `While(a < 0) a += n;` (when `a` is a negative number)
- `a = n*q + r` that means `r = a - n*q` While `q is the integer division of a/n` which means `a%n == a - n * Math.toIntExact(a/n)` Which is sufficient when `a` is a positive number.
- While `a` is a negative number, we can use `(a%n + n) % n` Which will give you module.

> Case Scenario on Clock:

if it is now 9 O'clock, what time after 4 hours `=>` 9+4 = 13h `=>` 13%12=1 `while 12 is the cycle number in the clock`

What if we need to calculate time before `24` hours (Yesterday) from now which is `9 O'clock`, then:
`24(2*12)` `=>` Yesterday Means `9-24 = -15h` While the right answer is `9` , to solve this we will use `(a%n + n) % n` While `a%n == (a - n * Math.toIntExact(a/n))` then `-15 - 12 * Math.toIntExact(-15/12) = -3` => `-3 + 12 = 9` => `9%12` => `9 - 12 * Math.toIntExact(9/12) = 9` Which is the right answer.

> This is the code for the clock Scenario:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt(); // a = -15
    int n = scanner.nextInt(); // cycle = 12

    int reminder = a - (n * Math.toIntExact(a / n));
    int reminder_plus_n = (reminder + n);
    int modulo = reminder_plus_n - (n * Math.toIntExact(reminder_plus_n / n));
    System.out.println(modulo); // Answer = 9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the quotient together with the remainder to calculate the count and remainder.**

Here is some code that I wrote for a Minecraft plugin.

```java
public class Division {
    public static ModuloDivResult divideMod(double a, double b) {
        double remainder = a % b;
        return new ModuloDivResult((a / b) - (remainder / b), remainder);
    }
}
```

*We also need a container for both values.*

```java
public class ModuloDivResult {
    private double remainder;
    private double count;

    public ModuloDivResult(double count, double remainder) {
        this.remainder = remainder;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public double getRemainder() {
        return remainder;
    }

    public double getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```